# Tareas en segundo plano desde cPanel

Tags: laravel, queue

Tengo un proyecto en laravel el cual cuenta con tareas en segundo plano y no logro que se ejecuten en mi proyecto remoto, miestras que en el local se realizan a la perfección.
Hay alguien que me pueda ayudar? Que datos necesitan para esta ayuda?

Muchas gracias!!

he seguido la documentación de laravel - queue.
Este es mi codigo de jobs/CargaProductos:

````
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Imports\ProductosImport;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class CargaProductos implements ShouldQueue, WithChunkReading
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $id_tienda;

    public function __construct($id_tienda)
    {
        $this->id_tienda = $id_tienda;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Excel::filter('chunk')->load(public_path('import/productos.xlsx'))
            ->chunk(500, function($results) {
                $import = new ProductosImport($this->id_tienda);
                Excel::import($import, $results);
            });

    }


    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 100;
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Hola. ¿Verificaste que tu aplicación no está en [Modo de Mantenimiento](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#maintenance-mode)? Según la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#maintenance-mode) las tareas programadas no funcionan en Modo Mantenimiento.

Comment: Por lo que veo en la documentación que me mandas "Modo de Mantenimiento" debo activar ese modo. Y nunca lo he activado y por otro lado en mi local funciona. Si estuviese en mantenimiento no debería fallar también en el local?

Comment: No, no es que *debas* activar ese modo, el cual se activa, por lo general, cuando vas a hacer algún cambio (rápido) en la aplicación o si, Dios no lo permita, te hackean el sitio o cosas así, para que cuando se intente ir al sitio aparezca que está en modo mantenimiento, mientras resuelves el problema. Lo que sí debes es verificar si en remoto está activado el modo mantenimiento, porque de lo contrario las tareas programadas no funcionarán. Para asegurarte que estás en modo normal puedes ejecutar `php artisan up` en la consola del servidor remoto.

Comment: Por otra parte, siempre en el servidor remoto, convendría que actives el [Modo Debug](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#debug-mode) para obtener información más precisa de por qué no está funcionando debidamente la aplicación.

Comment: No, no hay caso. 
Mis jobs pasan directo a la tabla de failed_jobs.

Comment: ¿Probaste a activar el modo debug? Podría darte alguna pista sobre por qué están fallando las tareas. Por otra parte, ¿tienes definida alguna política para manejar las [tareas fallidas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs)? ¿En la tabla `failed_jobs` las entradas no te dicen nada sobre el motivo del fallo?

Comment: Siento que es muy avanzado para mi conocimiento.
Decidí dar un limite en el tamaño del archivo para que no sea extenso y se pueda ejecutar sin trabas.
Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda.